# How would I change this function to implement a Min Heap instead of max?

Tags: c

Does anyone know how I would make a min heap instead of max heap? this function creates a max heap but I have no idea how to make it a min.

```
void siftUp(int heap[], int n) {
        // Sift the value in heap[n] so that heap[1..n] is a heap
        int siftItem = heap[n];
        int child = n;
        int parent = child / 2;
        while (parent > 0) {
            if (siftItem >= heap[parent]) {
                break;
            }
            heap[child] = heap[parent];         // Move the parent down
            child = parent;
            parent = child / 2;
        }
        heap[child] = siftItem;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to flip the comparison condition:

```
if (siftItem <= heap[parent])
```

Comment: it actually just orders them in acceding order.